# DataFrame from list of list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have list of list

```
u=[[1, 1], [2, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
```

I want to create a DataFrame using pandas where the rows are indexed by the length of u and the columns are given by the group of numbers inside this list of list.

I want the element of this DataFrame to be the frequency in which the elements occurs. For example, from above, I want to get the following table
[image: DataFrame from the list of list]

In the Table above the column with 1 gives the number of ones in each list while 2 gives a number of 2. In cell (1,1) the number 2 was obtained by counting the number of ones in the first list that is [1,1]. In cell (2,1) the number 3 was obtained by counting a number of ones in the list [2,1,1,1] while in the cell (2,2) the number two was obtained by counting the frequency of two in the list [2,1,1,1] the same procedure was repeated throughout.

I know that to count number of repeating elements in a list I have to use count. for example
    [1,1,1,2].count(1)=3
what I want to know is to use Pandas so that I get the DataFrame as above. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Counter` in order to transform list in to dictionary. Then using `pd.DataFrame` to convert that dictionary

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
df = pd.DataFrame([Counter(u_) for u_ in u]).fillna(0)
```

**note** that there is no 4 in here, you can manually add it to dictionary or just add the 4 column in dataframe after i.e. `df[4] = 0`

Answer (score 1):

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is useful to do this:

First create `Counter` instances from the lists and use these to instanciate DataFrames:

```
u=[[1, 1], [2, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([Counter(e) for e in u]).fillna(0)
df[4] = 0.0
print(df)
```

#### Output

```
   1     2    3    4
0  2   0.0  0.0  0.0
1  3   1.0  0.0  0.0
2  4   4.0  0.0  0.0
3  5  10.0  1.0  0.0
4  6  20.0  6.0  0.0
```

This is possible, because under the hood `Counter` behaves like a `dict`.