# Nested JSON file flattened and stored as CSV

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a json file into csv format, here is a snippet of the json file(sample3.json) :

```js
{
  "x" : {
    "-tst1" : {
      "da" : "8C",
      "d" : "df4",
      "h" : 0,
      "i" : 1,
      "s" : false,
      "t" : 1501394756245
    },
    "-tst2" : {
      "da" : "8C",
      "d" : "\\df&*",
      "h" : 0,
      "i" : 0,
      "s" : true,
      "t" : 1501394946296
    }
  }   
}
```

These are some solutions that I've tried but I'm unabe to get any of them working:
[Convert list into a pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593104/convert-list-into-a-pandas-data-frame)
[DataFrame from list of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42332463/dataframe-from-list-of-list)
[Convert Nested JSON to Excel using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404961/convert-nested-json-to-excel-using-python)

How can I get a table like the one below that I can export to a csv?

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWHVI.png)

I've tried several different ways but I'm not getting anywhere...the furthest I've gotten is getting the values into a list.

It seems like it would be simple but I'm more of a sql guy not python.

I appreciate any help.

```
import json
import ast
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import itertools
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import openpyxl
from collections import Counter


test = open('sample3.json').read()
data = json.loads(test)
vals = data['x']

for key in vals.keys():
    v = vals.values
    t = list(vals.values())
    #pd.DataFrame(t)
#print(type(t)) 
#print('Separator')
#print(type(v))  




df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(t)  #error:  Not enough values to unpack...expected 2, got 1.
print(df)
```

Comment: fyi, I know i'm not using all the libraries, I've just accumulated them from all the solutions I've tried.

Comment: possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/how-can-i-convert-json-to-csv

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert JSON to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/how-can-i-convert-json-to-csv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want, but does this work for you?

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('sample3.json') as f: # this ensures opening and closing file
    a = json.loads(f.read())

data = a["x"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df.transpose())
```

my output:

```
          d  da  h  i      s              t
-tst1   df4  8C  0  1  False  1501394756245
-tst2  df&*  8C  0  0   True  1501394946296
```

you can then do:

```
df.transpose().to_csv('myfilename.csv')
```

---

in response to your comment, you could do:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

a = """{"z" : { "y" : { "x" : { "-v" : { "d1" : "8C:F", "d2" : "8.0", "t" : 3, "x" : 45 }, "-u" : { "d1" : "8C", "d2" : "8.00", "t" : 5, "x" : 45 } } } }}"""

js = json.loads(a)

print pd.DataFrame.from_dict(js['z']['y']['x'], orient='index')
```

(the json you posted was missing a `}`, but I assume that was a copy/paste error)

Comment: Yes!!  This is perfect.  Exactly what I wanted...Will this scale to large datasets efficiently?

Comment: for certain values of 'large' and 'efficient', yes. :)

Comment: Could I bother you for a little more help?  I have a second json file like this

`
{"z" : {
    "y" : {
      "x" : {
        "-v" : {
          "d1" : "8C:F",
          "d2" : "8.0",
          "t" : 3,
          "x" : 45
        },
        "-u" : {
          "d1" : "8C",
          "d2" : "8.00",
          "t" : 5,
          "x" : 45
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`
Can the script you gave be modified for this file format?

Comment: @Gee you have to de-nest it - I'll add the code to my answer